# Treat CLI arguments with special characters as string with Python Click

Tags: python, bash, python-click

When taking in the arguments how do you treat everything after the `python jcr.py` as a string as opposed to a bash command?

Example 1:

```
input: `python jcr.py ~!@`

throws: `bash: !@: event not found`

desired: `received:->~!@<-`
```

Example 2:

```
input: `python jcr.py (`

throws: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

desired: `received:->(<-`
```

---

*jcr.py:*

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument('cmd', nargs=-1)
def jcr(cmd):
    click.echo('received:->%s<-' % (" ".join(cmd)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jcr()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are special characters you can add single or double quotes around the symbols and parse these in your python file

Comment: The CLI is gonna be used by external users so ideally, I wouldn't have to enforce that they place quotes around the symbols

Comment: @sidd99 - this is beyond your control. Your Python code was not failing to begin with - it was the shell invocation of the python interpreter. Special shell characters, such as `(`, `~` or `!` must be escaped in the terminal (or calling script), or else, the shell will process them according to its conventions.

Comment: @amitai-irron I see, so does this mean there's nothing I can do?

Comment: @sidd99: the real question her is why you want to pass, to a tool that runs under **bash**, characters that are usually reserved for **bash**'s usage. Your users will be used to using **bash**, and expect these characters to have special meaning, so expecting them to escape is reasonable.

Comment: What you can do is ask user to enter every command line arguments between the double quote otherwise there is no way you can enter special characters without escaping it